# How to select all elements in DOM apart from one div and the children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I need to select all the elements in the DOM using JQuery/JS, apart from one div. The only issue is, I also need to exempt the divs children in the selection. For example:

```
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<div>
  3
  <li>3.1</li>
  <li>3.2</li>
</div>

$('*').not('div and children');

//should give me li 1 and 2, but not div 3 or li 3.1/3.2
```

I've tried the `.not()` keyword, but it only selects the parent div, and the children are still affected.

Comment: You can't use `div` in `ul`. It isn't valid in html.

Comment: @Mohammad I know, just an example :-) I'm actually doing it on a bootstrap modal

Comment: Just omit the immediate children, or all descendants below them as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select all elements with `$('body *')` but not `div` and not children of `div` with `.not('div, div *')`

```js
$('body *').not('div, div *').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<div>
  3
  <li>3.1</li>
  <li>3.2</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('*').not('div, div > li');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log($('body *').not('div, div li, script'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<div>
  3
  <li>3.1</li>
  <li>3.2</li>
</div>
```